# MYSQL query for summing occurence of some column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have such MYSQL table for logins:

```
id---name---location---login_date
----------------------------------
1----mike----usa-----21.08.2012
2----tony----uk------22.08.2012
3----tony----uk------23.08.2012
4----david--france---24.08.2012
5----mike----usa-----25.08.2012
6----tony----uk------26.08.2012
7----ash--france----27.08.2012
```

I need this output. Results will be GROUPed BY name, ORDERED BY login_times.
What would be the fastest query for this situation?

```
login_times---name
3-------------tony
2-------------mike
1-------------david
1-------------ash
```

Comment: A query to get the result you want is simple. "fastest" will depend on much more than the SQL statement alone; your indexing, server hardware specification, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'login_times', name 
FROM logins 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY login_times DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e176/9

But [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: You forgot to ORDER by login_times

Comment: I get whole table with "SELECT *" and then with "foreach" I loop through response and increased login_time of related array key :)